# Multiprocessing is so slow and using too much CPU, any alternatives?

Tags: multiprocessing

I tried to web scraping on HKEX website for multiple stocks, to speed up the process I used multiprocessing, yet this method run for a few minutes and sometimes crashed my computing using too much CPU. Any alternative?
P.S. the "S:/Model/JT/Tickers.xlsx" is just a normal excel file including the stock tickers.

```
import multiprocessing
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os, time, random
import numpy as np
import datetime
import locale
import openpyxl
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
lastBusDay = datetime.datetime.today()
shift = datetime.timedelta(max(1, (lastBusDay.weekday() + 6) % 7 - 3))
lastBusDay = lastBusDay - shift
lastBusDay.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

LBD = str(lastBusDay)
LBD = LBD[0:10]

shift = datetime.timedelta(max(1, (lastBusDay.weekday() + 6) % 7 - 3))
lastBusDay = lastBusDay - shift
LBD1 = str(lastBusDay)
LBD1 = LBD1[0:10]

t = LBD1
tm1 = LBD
t_list = list(t)
t_list[4] = "/"
t_list[7] = "/"
t = ''.join(t_list)
tm1_list = list(tm1)
tm1_list[4] = "/"
tm1_list[7] = "/"
tm1 = ''.join(tm1_list)

t = t.replace('/', '-')
tm1 = tm1.replace('/', '-')

filename = "S:/Model/JT/Tickers.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(filename, engine='openpyxl')

# Extract data from the first column and convert it to a list
tickers = df.iloc[:, 0].tolist()


def get_ccass(ticker, date):
    service = Service(executable_path=r"S:/Model/JT/chromedriver.exe")
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    # Initialize Chrome driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"S:/Lily/chromedriver.exe", options=options)
    # Navigate to website URL
    driver.get('https://www3.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/searchsdw.aspx')

    # Wait for page to load fully
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    # Find textbox and input number
    input_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "txtStockCode")))
    input_box.send_keys(ticker)

    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    button_xpath = '//*[@id="onetrust-reject-all-handler"]'
    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, button_xpath))
    )

    # Scroll the button into view
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", button)
    # Use JavaScript to click the button
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    element = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="txtShareholdingDate"]')

    # Change the value of the element to 2023/05/20
    driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{date}')", element)

    # Locate the button using its XPath
    button_xpath = '//*[@id="btnSearch"]'
    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, button_xpath))
    )

    # Scroll the button into view
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", button)

    # Use JavaScript to click the button
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

    # Wait for new page to load
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    value_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                        '#pnlResultSummary > div > div.ccass-search-datarow.ccass-search-total > div.shareholding > div.value')
    value = value_element.text
    driver.quit()
    return value


def mp_worker(data):
    data_t = get_ccass(data, t)
    data_t = float(data_t.replace(',', ''))
    data_tm1 = get_ccass(data, tm1)
    data_tm1 = float(data_tm1.replace(',', ''))
    change = (data_tm1 - data_t)
    # format the values using the locale module
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')  # use the default locale settings
    data_t = locale.format_string('%d', data_t, grouping=True)
    data_tm1 = locale.format_string('%d', data_tm1, grouping=True)
    change = locale.format_string('%d', change, grouping=True)
    return ([data, data_t, data_tm1, change])


def mp_handler(data_list):
    # write the header row to the output csv file
    file_name = 'results_' + tm1 + '.csv'
    exfile_name = 'results_' + tm1 + '.xlsx'
    file_path = os.path.abspath("S:\\Model\JT\\CCASS results\\"+file_name)
    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(','.join(['ticker', t, tm1, 'change']) + '\n')
    with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as p:
        with open(file_path, 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n', delimiter=',')
            for result in p.imap_unordered(mp_worker, data_list):
                writer.writerow([result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3]])
    read_file = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    read_file.to_excel("S:\\Model\JT\\CCASS results\\"+exfile_name, index=None, header=True)
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("S:\\Model\JT\\CCASS results\\"+exfile_name)
    worksheet = workbook.active
    column_width = 25
    worksheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = column_width
    worksheet.column_dimensions['C'].width = column_width
    worksheet.column_dimensions['D'].width = column_width
    # Save the modified workbook
    workbook.save("S:\\Model\JT\\CCASS results\\"+exfile_name)
    os.remove(file_path)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # code to prepare the data list
    data_list = tickers
    mp_handler(data_list)
```

I tried to web scraping on HKEX website for multiple stocks, to speed up the process I used multiprocessing, yet this method run for a few minutes and sometimes crashed my computing using too much CPU.

Comment: it looks like your program waits a lot for responses from web servers. The waiting can be parallelized without processes, e.g. with async functions or threads. It would be interesting to know how much time is spent on waiting, javascript execution and process spawning.

Comment: multiprocessing itself has a relatively low CPU load. It is your scripts that are using the CPU, and multiprocessing allows you to maximize their performance. The most (and perhaps only) effective solution is to reduce the CPU load of your scripts. Since you are doing chrome-based web scraping, if you could do more low-level scraping such as using Scrapy instead, it would greatly reduce the load. Also, you should check to see if the site you are trying to use provides some public APIs.